# How do I know if my flag was 'helpful'?

Tags: discussion, flagging

If I raise a flag on a question or an answer in a review queue,
how do I find the flag was considered helpful later?

Are the items marked as 'reviewed' considered as 'helpful'?
I raised 79 helpful flags (from my badge tracker), but cannot find which are them.

Comment: Click on the link in your profile, only you can see the link, should be self explanatory. The link is “helpful flags” can’t miss it

Answer (score 2):

The "79 helpful flags" on your profile impact section should link to a page that lists all the flags you raised. You should see a link to the post you flagged, what type of flag you raised, and what the outcome was.

[image: impact]

For information it should link to `https://superuser.com/users/flag-summary/your-user-number`

In your case that would be https://superuser.com/users/flag-summary/137183

Note that this page is only viewable by you as well as site moderators.

Comment: A universal link is https://superuser.com/users/flag-summary/current . The trick with `current` is documented here: [Documentation for Stack Exchange engine URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332251/355310).

Comment: And the link is in the "Activity" of your user page not on the "Profile" tab